# Deleting list items in a csv file from the user interface

Tags: python, csv, flask

i have this code that allows me save user input in a csv file and then from the csv file, display it as a list on my web application. i would also like to allow the users delete these items as they choose to. Is there anyway to do this?.
Ps. i'm a python beginner

**this is the code below**

```
class ReusableForm(Form):
name = TextField('Name:', validators=[validators.required()])

@app.route("/addchannel", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form_data():

    form = ReusableForm(request.form)
    print(form.errors)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        fieldname = ['name']
        if form.validate():

            flash('Channel successfully added! ')
        else:
            flash('Error: All the form fields are required. ')

        with open('channelname.csv', 'a') as file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames= fieldname)
            writer.writerow({'name': name})

    reader = csv.reader(open('channelname.csv'))
    csv_data = [row for row in reader]

    return render_template('addchannel.html', form=form , data= csv_data)
```

Comment: So this code is not working? Throwing off error?

Comment: Please specific your issue.

Comment: its working fine (displaying the list on the webpage) i dont have any code in there for deleting rows because i dont know where to start from. hence my question on how to delete rows..

Comment: when i run this particular code i have posted, it does all that i want it to do. but now i want to add a delete functionality of which i do not know how to begin.

Comment: perhaps the code i added wasnt necessary